# Silverlight CrossDomainError on IISExpress 7.5

Tags: silverlight-4.0, iis-7.5, firewall, iis-express, windows-firewall

I am getting this issue only on my PC. I am using IIS Express 7.5 to host WCF services on my Local Port. I tried in different PC's its working good.

Error:

> [CrossDomainError] Arguments:
>   **https//localhost:44300/ClientSyncService.svc** Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide
>   sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See
>   http//go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60831.0&File=System.ServiceModel.dll&Key=CrossDomainError
>   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result).

I have `clientaccesspolicy.xml` at the root of https://localhost:44300/clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have no idea whats wrong with my PC.

Any Help is Appreciated

Comment: I am able to Access Services if the Application is non SSL. If App is Secured I am still getting security Exception. With Secured/SSL App it is not even calling for clientaccesspolicy.xml it is throws security exception. I guess this might be something related to Firewall or Port?

Answer (score 0):

do you access to your service in browser?
may be following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324973/crossdomainerror-on-same-domain) useful for your problem.
[this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) so is useful for this problem