# Silverlight: ImageTools.ExtendedImage Loading External URL Image NOT Working at all

Tags: image, silverlight, url

I'm using the ImageTools library (imagetools.codeplex.com) to load an image from external URL.

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Blue"
        Width="466" Height="204" >

    <Image Name="theImage" />

    <Button x:Name="btnTest" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="-200" Click="btnTest_Click"
                Width="100" Height="23"
                Content="Test Button">
    </Button>

</Canvas>
```

Init:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Encoders.AddEncoder<PngEncoder>();
        Decoders.AddDecoder<PngDecoder>();
        Encoders.AddEncoder<JpegEncoder>();
        Decoders.AddDecoder<JpegDecoder>();
    }
```

Then:

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendedImage ei = new ExtendedImage();
        // ei.UriSource = new Uri(@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"); // NOT working
        ei.UriSource = new Uri(@"/Images/header.png", UriKind.Relative); // Working

        ei.LoadingCompleted += new EventHandler((ss, ee) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                theImage.Source = ei.ToBitmap();
            });
        });
    }
```

I found that loading a local file `/Image/header.png` is working, but loading an external URL image (`https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png`) is not working at all.

It behaves crazy: once I click the Test Button, the LayoutRoot canvas disappears.

However, according to this discussion: http://imagetools.codeplex.com/discussions/250624
Loading an external URL image should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be related with UriType ?

Relative,Absolute,RelativeOrAbsolute

```
ei.UriSource =
new Uri(@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); // works ?
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind(v=vs.95).aspx

Hope helps!

**EDIT:** You need a file like that http://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml otherwise SL throws SecurityException normally.

For crossdomain implementation see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1325011/413032

http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2008/11/08/Silverlight-clientaccesspolicyxml-files-for-the-Enterprise-(Part-1-of-2).aspx

Comment: Add ei.LoadingFailed it says why it fails

Comment: I got System.Security.SecurityException It means you need CrossDomain.xaml http://stackoverflow.com/q/4174317/413032. CrossDomain is a file it says my software can reach this channels.These ports..., These remote files...